# React, export components to index.js then import them from folder (React native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, function, react-i18next

I'm trying to export my components with one index.js while exporting them with withTranslation, here's my architecture:

```
- screen1
-- components
--- Component1.js
--- Component2.js
--- index.js
-- Screen1.js
```

Component1.js looks like (same as Component2.js):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";

class Component1 extends Component {

    render() {

        const {t} = this.props;

        return (
            <View>
                 <Text>{t('translatedText')}</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default withTranslation()(Component1)
```

index.js:

```js
export * from './Component1';
export * from './Component2';
```

Screen1.js:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View } from 'react-native'
import { withTranslation } from "react-i18next";

import { Component1, Component2 } from './components';

class Screen1 extends Component {

    render() {

        return (
            <View>
                <Component1 />
                <Component2 />
            </View>
        )
    }
}

export default withTranslation()(Screen1);
```

But it doesn't work I get this error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

I've tried to use `export { Component1 }` instead of `export default withTranslation()(Component1);`
And it works, but I need to translate my app...
Any ideas? I would like to keep this kind of architecture where I can call easily all my components needed for the screen.

Comment: You can try using  ```import Component1 from './Component1';export {Component1}``` in components/index.js file instead of ```export * from './Component1';```

Comment: Glad it worked out